# Optimizing parameter estimates by minimizing chi^2 in iterative procedure

Tags: chi-squared-test, maximum-likelihood, algorithms, model

I need to minimize my Chi^2 (bottom-left in figure 1) by adjusting parameter-values in a MLE-procedure (or something alike). The chi^2 (red) is a goodness-of-fit measure. It expresses how well the parameters can ‘predict’ the observed data. Chi^2 thus has to be small (which ensures my actual observations and predicted observations are not statistically different).

I displayed some hypothetical data below.

> Parameters:           Probabilities
>
> Frequencies:          Observed amount of occurrences of  behaviour x
>
> Predicted proportion:      Function of the parameters. In the example:
>
> - Cell 1: Parameter 1 * Parameter 2
> - Cell 2: Parameter 1 * Parameter 2 + (1- Parameter 1)
>
> Predicted frequencies:        Sum of frequencies * Predicted proportion
>
> Chi^2 (on the right):         (Predicted frequency – Frequency)^2 / Predicted Frequency
>
> Chi^2 (red):          Sum of Chi^2

In excel, I can use the solver GRG nonlinear which makes n-iterations to find the minimal chi^2. In my case, the iteration is as follows:

> 1. First iteration?
>
> 1a.   YES:    set parameters to 0.5
>
> 1b.   NO: Adjust parameters to minimize chi^2 (red)
>
> 2. Calculate predicted proportion
> 3. Calculate predicted frequency
> 4. Calculate Chi^2
> 5. Sum Chi^2 (red)
> 6. Iteration 100?
>
> 6a.   NO: Back to one 1b.
>
> 6b.   YES:    Stop

But I don’t want to use excel. Instead, I want to use R, Python or Matlab (preferably Python). The 1b. in the iteration is my ‘black box’, my problem. I need a method  (or an algorithm) to minimize my chi^2 in a reasonable amount of iterations, i.e. adjust my parameters in a smart way.  Furthermore, the method  must be able to handle constraints (my parameters have to be estimated between 0 and 1).

[image]

Comment: Maybe you can comment on the motivation of this exercise.  Just guessing here, but maybe you have some sort of contingency table that you are trying to adjust to match observed margins?  Also, 5 unknowns and 16 equations in general would be an over-constrained problem.  Perhaps you don't actually mean *equations* (one thing being set equal to another)?

Comment: a yes, you are right. They are just formulas (which I will adjust). 
I am trying to create a script which enables me to build a 'quad-model'. It is a probabilistic model used to predict 5 things: Activation of associations in memory (P1 & P2), the ability to choose which answer is correct (P3), the ability to overcome certain biases (B4), and a guessing probability (P5) (for an overview, see Conrey, F. R., Sherman, J. W., Gawronski, B., Hugenberg, K., & Groom, C. (2006). Separating multiple processes in implicit social cognition: The Quad-Model of implicit task performance).

Comment: This makes little sense, & may not even be a statistical question. It seems like it may be a theoretical model from cognitive science. Recognize that no one here is going to want to read a paper to answer your Q & then build a computational model for you. There is a [cogsci.SE] SE site, but I doubt anyone there would want to do that for you either; they may be willing to answer substantive questions about the theory though, if that is what you really have.

Comment: No I understand. I basically just want an algorithm to optimize my parameters (by minimizing chi-squared), regardless of the theory. I will try to explain myself by editing the text.

Comment: What to select as an algorithm depends (among other things) on the model and on the statistical nature of the data.  Unless you provide those details, we will not be in a position to provide good answers to your question.

Comment: I may be able to help, how is parameter 1 and parameter related to chi^2, I don't see them being used in the function that you are trying to minimize. Did I miss anything here?

Comment: the parameters are used to estimate the 'predicted proportion', which are used to estimate the predicted frequency. The chi^2's are computed by (predicted- frequency)^2 / predicted frequency. The chi^2 I want to minimize is the sum of these caclulated chi^2's. So if I change my parameters, my predicted proportion, predicted frequency and therefore Chi^2 (and it's sum) will also change. Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are looking for software to do constrained black-box optimization, eg,
$$
\min f(x) \quad \mbox{subject to } g(x)<c, h(x) = d
$$
In your case, $f(x)$ is the sum of $\chi^2$ residuals, and $x$ are your parameters (probabilities, I guess?) and $g(x)$ is maybe the constraints that $0<x<1$ and I would assume $h(x) = \sum x = 1$.

Without knowing what software you are using, it would be pointless to offer suggestions as far as specific routines are concerned, but a couple keywords to research would be "gradient ascent" and "Nelder-Mead."  But really no one writes their own method for a one-off optimization, instead they use libraries or languages that already provides such routines.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I adjusted my question in the hopes I am a bit more clear. My parameters are indeed probabilities but they don't have to add up to 1. I would love to use a library which offers me a routine. I am familiar with R, Python, and Matlab. I prefer to use Python. I hope the information is sufficient to suggest a more specific routine.